# Gson parse Json with array

Tags: java, json, gson

I am having some trouble building a class which will parse out gson as I expect it to.

I created a class.

```
public class JsonObjectBreakDown {
    public String type; 
    public List<String> coordinates = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

And called

```
JsonObjectBreakDown p = gson.fromJson(withDup, JsonObjectBreakDown.class);
```

Below is my json

```
  {
   "type":"Polygon",
   "coordinates":[
      [
         [
            -66.9,
            18.05
         ],
         [
            -66.9,
            18.05
         ],
         [
            -66.9,
            18.06
         ],
         [
            -66.9,
            18.05
         ]
      ]
   ]
}
```

I have used gson before successfully, but never with an array like this. Should I not be using the List/ArrayList?

I get the error message;

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 31
```

OpenCSV code

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("c:\\Json.csv"));
String tmp = reader.readNext();
CustomObject tmpObj = CustomObject(tmp[0], tmp[1],......);
```

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/serializing-and-deserializing-json-from.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you have an **array of arrays of arrays of floating point numbers** in your JSON. Your class should be

```
public class JsonObjectBreakDown {
    public String type; 
    public List<List<float[]>> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Parsing with the above and trying

```
System.out.println(p.coordinates.size());
System.out.println(p.coordinates.get(0).size());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p.coordinates.get(0).get(0)));
```

yields

```
1
2
[-66.9, 18.05]
```

Comment: @user2524908 Yes, but if you are using Java 7, you don't need to put the argument in the constructor call. Just `new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: hm, I am getting 'Unterminated object at line 1 column 31.' I assume that means there is a problem with my json. I validated it correct format with some online json validator.

Comment: @user2524908 Can you edit your question with the actual json String you are using? I ran the code and it works.

Comment: I updated the json. Unfortunately it looks like my openvsc parser is stripping out one of the closing " after Polygon when I output it in eclipse

Comment: @user2524908 Is your JSON contained in a CSV string?

Comment: Yes my json is contained in a csv, which I am initially parsing using opencsv. Added code above

Comment: @user2524908 Before you go and fix how the CSV parsing happens, try to write the String out yourself with proper escaping and checking if that works for you.

Comment: Yeah that works great! if I just pass through a string containing the correct json format what you provided works. So the csv reader is messing things up

Comment: @user2524908 I guess. I don't know that library but there's probably a configuration about how to handle quotes.

Comment: Thanks for all the help on that issue. I appreciate it

Comment: @user2524908 You're welcome. Please consider accepting the answer. Also, you can always ask another question for the CSVReader by providing details on what you've tried.